# Lotus notes datetime

Tags: datetime, lotus-notes

I have a datetime column in lotus notes which has value like 01/02/2019 01:01:01 PM.

I need to export the data into csv file in the below format:
`2019-01-02 13:01:01.000`

Tried changing the column properties in the view but while exporting the data is changed to 01/02/2019 01:01:01.

Here AM/PM is getting ignored.

Please suggest a way to do this properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula in your view column, where `DateField` is the field with date.

```
year := @Text(@Year(DateField));
month := @Right("0" + @Text(@Month(DateField)) ; 2);
day := @Right("0" + @Text(@Day(DateField)) ; 2);
hour := @Right("0" + @Text(@Hour(DateField)) ; 2);
minute := @Right("0" + @Text(@Minute(DateField)) ; 2);
second := @Right("0" + @Text(@Second(DateField)) ; 2);


year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + 
hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ".000"
```

Those `@Right` functions will pad your values with zeroes when needed.

Comment: Thanks Roman. What if I need only YYYY-MM-DD from the same datetime example? Will the same solution work? I tried but it gives me error.

Comment: Of course it’ll work. Try `year + "-" + month + "-" + day`. You probably got the error because you left a plus sign at the end of the formula.